# Simulate keybord input in c#

Tags: c#

It has been asked before, but these questions are really old (7-10 years ago) and answers very long, and I imagine it can be done in less than 500 lines.

Simple thing - console application that simulates button press. I launch it, and for example after 5 seconds button V is pressed. If I have for example Notepad active, I will see V appear in editor.

How I would see it in code, its obviously fake code that won't work:

```cs
Keyboard.Press("V");
```

Comment: If you don't want to bother with working solutions you may have found, you can use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)

Comment: @Cid looks interesting, might be easier to achieve what I want than using c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Install-Package WindowsInput` () and then use this code:

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Keyboard.PressAsync("V");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }

});

public class Keyboard
{
    public static async Task PressAsync(string key)
    {
        await Simulate.Events().Click(key).Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have .NET 6.0 at the moment, and my internet connection is not exactly fast, so I can't check it at this very moment, but I will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: In fact, you don't need .net 6.0. I just mentioned that if you use .net 6.0, how to install this package in a console app, which I think it's not related to your question. To resolve such a misunderstanding, I edited my answer.